# search form codeigniter GET_POST

Tags: codeigniter

Here I ant desired url like in php but how can I code this in codeigniter with controller, model, and view? someone has a code with this?

http://mysite.com/search?query=batman&cat=movie

My Controller

```
function index(){
//some code to get search query value
}
```

My Model

```
function getSearch(){
//some code to get search value
}
```

My View

```
<form action="http://mysite.com/search/'; ?>">
   <input name="query" value="">
   <input name="cat" value="">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I want also to retrieve the seesion in text field after submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should specify the method of the form 
   e.g.
   `<form action="http://mysite.com/search/" method="post">`
2. use this to fetch the record
   `$query = $this->input->post('query');`
   `$cat = $this->input->post('cat');`
3. In order to retrieve the type text in to the text field, use set_value
   e.g.
   `<input name="query" value="<?php set_value('cat') ?>">`
   `<input name="cat" value="<?php set_value('query') ?>">`

hope this helps!